# Different width result in different browser $("#div1").width()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, internet-explorer-8

I am using jquery to determine the width of the control:-

```
$("#div1").width();
```

There is a difference in width of the div between IE8 (in compatibility view) and Firefox. Width is not same.

e.g 
ie : 1887
FF : 1898

How to tackle it?

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset stylesheet or anything? Padding and margins are going to differ by default.

Comment: You have to give us more than that....What is the markup the DIV is in, are there CSS styles applied to it, do you use a reset CSS, what is inside it...

Comment: @Gumbo. You are senior guy...stop complaining man.
@Nick Crave: I am using CSS...

Comment: I was just asking. Maybe you had a reason for that, who knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the difference between the browsers' display exists because of their different perceptions of the CSS box model. The IE does interprete it another way than Firefox does (e.g. the `padding` property is treated differently).

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Can you just tell me how padding is treated differently....?

Comment: This might help explain the difference in the box model between IE and other browsers

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-did-internet-explorer-get-the-box-model-right/

Comment: Short version: Early versions of the IE took account of the padding in the `width` property whereas Firefox did / does not. For further information, see the video Catfish posted.